# Update Form with 'choice_list' to Symfony >= 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I want to update a form class to Symfony2.8 (and later to Symfony3). Now the form is converted except one attribute, the `choice_list`, that is not supported anymore. And I don't know how to do this.

I have the following form type that is defined also as a service:

```
class ExampleType extends AbstractType
{

    /** @var Delegate */
    private $delegate;

    public function __construct(Delegate $delegate)
    {
        $this->delegate = $delegate;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('list', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choice_list' => new ExampleChoiceList($this->delegate),
            'required'=>false)
        );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'ExampleClass',
            ));
    }
}
```

And I have the following class for the choice list:

```
class ExampleChoiceList extends LazyChoiceList
{

    /** @var Delegate  */
    private $delegate;

    public function __construct(Delegate $delegate)
    {
        $this->delegate = $delegate;
    }


    /**
     * Loads the choice list
     * Should be implemented by child classes.
     *
     * @return ChoiceListInterface The loaded choice list
     */
    protected function loadChoiceList()
    {
        $persons = $this->delegate->getAllPersonsFromDatabase();
        $personsList = array();
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            $id = $person->getId();
            $personsList[$id] = (string) $person->getLastname().', '.$person->getFirstname();
        }
        return new ArrayChoiceList($personsList);
    }


}
```

The class ExampleChoiceList generate the choice list how I want to have it, and until now it worked. But the attribute `choice_list` is not supported anymore, and my question is "how do I get this converted without too much work?". I read that I should use simple `choice` but how I get that what I want (the specific label from the database) in Symfony 2.8. I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a `ChoiceListInterface` you are almost there.

I suggest you change the `ExampleChoiceList` to implement the `Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\ChoiceLoaderInterface` instead, it requires you implement 3 methods:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/ChoiceList/Loader/ExampleChoiceLoader.php

namespace AppBundle\Form\ChoiceList\Loader;

use Acme\SomeBundle\Delegate;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ArrayChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Loader\ChoiceLoaderInterface;

class ExampleChoiceLoader implements ChoiceLoaderInterface
{
    /** $var ArrayChoiceList */
    private $choiceList;

    /** @var Delegate  */
    private $delegate;

    public function __construct(Delegate $delegate)
    {
        $this->delegate = $delegate;
    }

    /**
     * Loads the choice list
     * 
     * $value is a callable set by "choice_name" option
     *
     * @return ArrayChoiceList The loaded choice list
     */
    public function loadChoiceList($value = null)
    {
        if (null !== $this->choiceList) {
            return $this->choiceList;
        }

        $persons = $this->delegate->getAllPersonsFromDatabase();
        $personsList = array();
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            $label = (string) $person->getLastname().', '.$person->getFirstname();
            $personsList[$label] = (string) $person->getId();
            // So $label will be displayed and the id will be used as data
            // "value" will be ids as strings and used for post
            // this is just a suggestion though
        }

        return $this->choiceList = new ArrayChoiceList($personsList);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * $choices are entities or the underlying data you use in the field
     */
    public function loadValuesForChoices(array $choices, $value = null)
    {
        // optimize when no data is preset
        if (empty($choices)) {
            return array();
        }

        $values = array();
        foreach ($choices as $person) {
            $values[] = (string) $person->getId();
        }

        return $values;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * 
     * $values are the submitted string ids
     *
     */
    public function loadChoicesForValues(array $values, $value)
    {
        // optimize when nothing is submitted
        if (empty($values)) {
            return array();
        }

        // get the entities from ids and return whatever data you need.
        // e.g return $this->delegate->getPersonsByIds($values);
    }
}
```

register both the loader and the type as services so they are injected:

```
# app/config/services.yml

services:
    # ...
    app.delegate:
        class: Acme\SomeBundle\Delegate

    app.form.choice_loader.example:
        class: AppBundle\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\ExampleChoiceLoader
        arguments: ["@app.delegate"]

    app.form.type.example:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\ExampleType
        arguments: ["@app.form.choice_loader.example"]
```

Then change the form type to use the loader:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/ExampleType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use AppBundle\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\ExampleChoiceLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ExampleType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var ExampleChoiceLoader */
    private $loader;

    public function __construct(ExampleChoiceLoader $loader)
    {
        $this->loader = $loader;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options = array())
    {
        $builder->add('list', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choice_loader' => $this->loader,
            'required' => false,
        ));
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Thank for you help. I don't generate for each type a service, I used `'choice_loader' => new ExampleChoiceLoader($this->delegate),` now. And I write a class for all my cases that will be extend, so that I only must implement the `loadChoiceList` method.
I the case that I have 10 choice list from different types (and I want to use services for all), than I must also implement for each the loader and put them all in the constructor? Because in that case it seems a little bit oversized only for the choice lists.

Comment: When you declare a form type as a service, you can simply use the FQCN as usual, the injection is handled by the [`DependencyInjectionExtension`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjectionExtension.php). So you don't need to pass a constructed instance of the form type.

Comment: This way it would use only one loader instance in all your types. Maybe you could make an abstract type that all types needing the loader can extend.

Comment: Yes, I already done that. I wrote a abstract class that implements the `ChoiceLoaderInterface` and implements the methods `loadValuesForChoices` and `loadChoicesForValues`, so that there only return the ids and not the objects. In my choice lists classes I changed than the `implements LazyChoiceList` to `extends MyNewChoiceListHelper` and write only the `loadChoiceList` method. Here I only must change some lines (Mostly change the array labels and values). So I can converted it without to much changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'choice_list' is deprecated with SYmfony 2.8, but you can use 'choices' instead, which accepts an array as well. From [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/choice.html):

> The choices option is an array, where the array key is the item's
>   label and the array value is the item's value.

You must just pay attention than in Symfony 3.0, keys and values are inversed, and in Symfony 2.8, the recommended way is to use the new inversed order, and to specify 'choices_as_values' => true.

So, in the form type:

```
$builder->add('list', ChoiceType::class, array(
               'choices' => new ExampleChoiceList($this->delegate),
               'choices_as_values' => true,
               'required'=>false));
```

And in ExampleChoiceList:

```
protected function loadChoiceList()
    {
        $persons = $this->delegate->getAllPersonsFromDatabase();
        $personsList = array();
        foreach ($persons as $person) {
            $id = $person->getId();
            $personsList[(string) $person->getLastname().', '.$person->getFirstname()] = $id; // <== here
        }
        return new ArrayChoiceList($personsList);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so I suggest you don't use a ChoiceType at all, but a EntityType, as you seem to fetch all "Persons" from database. And to display "Last Name, First Name" as a label, use the 'choice_label' option. Assuming your entity is called 'Person':

```
$builder->add('list', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Person',
    'choice_label' => function ($person) {
        return $person->getLastName() . ', ' . $person->getFirstName();
    }
));
```

Comment: Sorry but your solution don't work. Now I get the following error:

`The option "choices" with value ExampleChoiceList is expected to be of type "null" or "array" or "\Traversable", but is of type "ExampleChoiceList".
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidOptionsException`

Comment: Sorry, didn't look the detail of ExampleChoiceList. Can you put the relevant code of LazyChoiceList, to see what is extended ?

Comment: Its from Symfony: `namespace Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList`. I used it to get the data for the `choice_list` but it seems that it make problems now. The LazyChoiceList implements `ChoiceListInterface`

Comment: Ok, so I suggest something I find simplier: use an EntityType instead of a ChoiseType. Please see my update.

Comment: That would be a solution if I use Doctrine for database queries, but I don't use Doctrine, I use Propel. So in my case your solution don't work. But thank you for your help.